# Synonym Request [stickies] to [sticky notes]

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tag-synonym-request

[stickies](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stickies) has 3 questions and [sticky-notes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sticky-notes) has 17. Sticky notes can be any operating system including OS X, while stickies seems to only be OS X.

[stickies](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stickies) should be a synonym of [sticky-notes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sticky-notes)

Additionally, [stickies](http://www.zhornsoftware.co.uk/stickies/) is an application that is windows only

Comment: The reason there's this *Stickies* application for Windows is probably the same one there's a *Caffeine* application for Windows by the same developer: He appears to be copying Mac OS X applications. [Caffeine for Mac](http://lightheadsw.com/caffeine/) has been around for more than five years.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Stickies ([stickies](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stickies)) is a particular implementation (bundled with OS X) of "sticky notes" note-taking software.

[image]

[sticky-notes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sticky-notes) seems to be about [the implementation bundled with Windows 7](http://windows.microsoft.com/en-US/windows7/products/features/sticky-notes).

Unless we plan on merging [mkv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mkv), [mp4](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/mp4) and [wmv](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/wmv) (different implementations of video/audio containers or something like that), or [firefox](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/firefox), [google-chrome](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/google-chrome), [safari](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/safari) and [internet-explorer](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/internet-explorer) (since they're essentially the same thing, web browsers) I **disagree**.

It's just the unfortunate similar naming that's problematic, and we cannot influence that. *Both [stickies](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/stickies) and [sticky-notes](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/sticky-notes) refer to software products, not generic concepts.

Comment: _For the sake of discussion_, I'm going to say I disagree with you here. The difference in _types_ of sticky notes is not the same difference in _types_ of data containers. Sticky notes are a physical tool that is being represented electronically by an analog to itself, by whatever name is being used. Data/audio/video containers do not have a physical analog in which they all represent.

Comment: @Raystafarian Maybe the example was not good enough. Let's replace it with this: Do you want to merge `safari`, `firefox`, `internet-explorer` and `google-chrome`? None of those have a generic name, but that's the only difference to this case. All are different implementations of "web browser".

Comment: Well, another example: `x264` is not a synonym of `h264`. It just so happens to have a similar name, but x264 implements h264 and not all people might know that.